# Android force traffic over internet while WiFi enabled

Tags: android, sockets

I'm starting to write an Android application to perform background monitoring of my web server. With WiFi enabled a problem will be that traffic is directed over that by default, I'd like to always use 3G for the HTTP request to check external availability as well. I know I could use this code to disable WiFi programmatically:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

But as it will be running in the background it's a bit clumsy and will interrupt other operations over WiFi while the check is in progress. Looking at the [Socket Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) I can't see any apparent way to achieve this. I'm wondering if there's any supported way to achieve this on a non-rooted phone? I have full control over the server so the protocol doesn't specifically have to be HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it would be an awfully dangerous feature for Android to allow.

- What about users who are on metered 3G plans? How would they feel if an app forced them to use a 3G connection and then bugged out or something and blew away their whole data quota without them even knowing it (thinking they were on WiFi)?
- Also, there could not be more than one active networks at a time.

**Possible Resolutions-**

- What you can do is to force disable the wifi network, when your application is active and then enable it later.
- Also, Try searching for a method called `requestRouteToHost`. It allows you to specify the network type and the host you want to find a route to.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't really thought through why it would be a bad idea to allow apps to perform this operation. Instead what I might do is add an option to only disable WiFi while the phone is locked. If I ever release as a public app I'll default that option to off and add a warning about traffic when turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do this in android since only one network connection is active at any given time. A similar question is posted here as well:

[Send HTTP request through 3G network without using WiFi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606031/send-http-request-through-3g-network-without-using-wifi)